# Getting odd error when changing string declaration

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I am declaring a string that is basically a list of designators, where yy is alpha and xxxx is numeric.

```
string sMyString = "('yy-xxxx','yy-xxxx','yy-xxxx','yy-xxxx','yy-xxxx','yy-xxxx')";

if(File.Exists(sFileLocation + sFileName))
{
    txtRunning.Text = "Starting db copy";
    File.Copy(sFileLocation + sFileName, sFileName, true);
    File.Copy(sDbLocation + "clipper.dbf", "clipper.dbf", true);
    File.Copy(sDbLocation + "clipper.dbt", "clipper.dbt", true);

    txtRunning.Text = "Starting datatable population";
    string connString = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data source=.\clipper.dbf";
    string mySelectQuery = "SELECT UPPER(TRIM(field1))," +
        " UPPER(TRIM(field2)), UPPER(TRIM(field3)), UPPER(TRIM(field4))" +
        " FROM `clipper` WHERE condition1 AND field1 IN " + sMyString +
        " ORDER BY field2;";

    DataTable dtClipper = new DataTable();
    DataTable dtNotFound = new DataTable();
    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(mySelectQuery, conn);
    adapter.Fill(dtClipper);
}
```

If I take out the parens, I get an error in a dataadapter.fill command, saying the function does not exist. I get the same error if I change it to a string literal, with or without the parens. If I leave it as is, with the parens and single quotes, it runs just fine.

I need it to be just the list, without the single quotes as I'm adding them to a dictionary to use as an incidence counter. What is it I'm missing?

Comment: Please include the relevant lines of code that actually produce the error.  Ie, `dataadapter.fill()`

Comment: @gilly3 - added. It works if I leave all the single quotes and parens, as soon as I take any of them out I get the error, even when declaring it as a string literal.

Comment: I can't see why you'd want to take out the single quotes or the parens.  What's your basis for assuming they're not needed?  It seems entirely appropriate for both to be required in looking at it.

Comment: because I split them into a dictionary <string, int>, so I can use the dictionary for an incidence counter. When I do that, I don't get a match when searching for the key of xx-yyyy when it's in the dictionary as 'xx-yyyy'.

Comment: agh, I'm an idiot. Never mind. I completely spaced I was adding it to my SQL command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is because you are using that string to run a SQL query, and without the quotes and parens, it's invalid sql.

You need to retain the quotes and parens in order for your SQL query to work.  If you *also* need to have access to the list as plain strings, then store it as a list.

```
List<string> myStrings = new List<String> {
    "yy-xxxx",
    "yy-xxxx",
    "yy-xxxx",
    "yy-xxxx",
    "yy-xxxx",
    "yy-xxxx"
};
string myStringsForSQL = string.Join(myStrings, "','");

string mySelectQuery = "SELECT UPPER(TRIM(field1)), " +
    "UPPER(TRIM(field2)), UPPER(TRIM(field3)), UPPER(TRIM(field4)) " +
    "FROM `clipper` WHERE condition1 AND field1 IN ('" + myStringsForSQL + "') " +
    "ORDER BY field2;";
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that on a subsequent edit. I added the parens inside the sql build rather than the string, and when I create my dictionary from it I just used regex to get rid of the single quotes. :-/ Although, I do like your solution as well. I'm still learning, a List didn't occur to me.